# wpf application memory increase while binding images

Tags: wpf

How can reduce image size while loading image in wpf application.

this is my code for uploading image

```
if (ofg.FileName != null && ofg.FileName.Length > 0)
            {
                ofg.OpenFile();
                FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(ofg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                Byte[] imgByteArr = new byte[fs1.Length];
                fs1.Read(imgByteArr, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs1.Length));
                fs1.Close();
                BitmapImage biImg = new BitmapImage();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgByteArr);
                biImg.BeginInit();
                biImg.StreamSource = ms;
                RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(biImg, BitmapScalingMode.LowQuality);
                biImg.EndInit();
                UserImage = biImg as ImageSource;
            }
```

Plz help me for reduce image size...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not call `OpenFile` without assigning the return value to a Stream variable, which you close later. Otherwise the Stream is never closed and thus produces a memory leak. When you open a FileStream, you do not need to call OpenFile at all.

You could further reduce memory consumption by avoiding the MemoryStream and also freezing the BitmapImage.

```
var biImg = new BitmapImage();
using (var fs = new FileStream(ofg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    biImg.BeginInit();
    biImg.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    biImg.StreamSource = fs;
    biImg.EndInit();
}
biImg.Freeze();
UserImage = biImg;
```

If you also need to reduce the number of pixels, you might set DecodePixelWidth or DecodePixelHeight (but not both if you want to preserve the aspect ratio):

```
biImg.BeginInit();
biImg.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
biImg.StreamSource = fs;
biImg.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
biImg.EndInit();
```